# Escape Razor Output (Change HtmlHelpers Textwriter)

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper

I want to create a Html-Helper, that Renders Html like the "native" HtmlHelper for Razor. Except that it should escape all output by replacing `"` with `\"`.

HtmlHelper-Code:

```
public static OtherContext ChangeContext(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper){
      return new OtherContext(htmlHelper);
}
```

OtherContext-Code:

```
public class OtherContext{

    private HtmlHelper _escapingHtmlHelper;

    public OtherContext(HtmlHelper){
         ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(...);
         _escapingHtmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(viewContext, ..., new RouteCollection());
    }

    public HtmlHelper Html{
         get{ return _escapingHtmlHelper;}
    }

}
```

View-Code:

```
using (var otherContext = Html.ChangeContext()) {
     otherContext.Html.TextBox(...)
}
```

The output rendered with otherContext.Html should all be escaped.

Expected Output => Replace('"', '\"'):

```
<input type=\"text\" value=\"\">
```

I tried implementing a custom WebViewPage and a custom TextWriter, that I created the Html-Helper with. But both were ignored.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is [razorengine] tag meaning you need this in the context of a template executed through [Antaris RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)?

Comment: Sorry. Seems like this is the wrong tag. It is in the meaning of the razor view engine for asp.net. I will change it.